# Are interdisciplinary questions about mathematics of musical instruments on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, scope

I have some mathematical questions that lie between music and mathematics, particularly applications of mathematics in building musical instruments.

As an example see this paper: **[The Mathematics of Musical Instruments](http://people.sju.edu/~rhall/newton/article.pdf)**

Are they on-topic here? In general, what sort of interdisciplinary questions are on-topic here?

Comment: I think such question is on-topic here if and only if it is interesting for mathematicians. -- That means in particular: if your question is solely interesting for people building musical instruments, then MathOverflow is unlikely to be the right place to ask it.

Comment: Here is an example of an earlier MO math/music question: "[Relation between math and piano music](http://mathoverflow.net/q/136241/6094)." There was some discussion in the comments concerning its appropriateness, but in the end it was well-received.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Thank you for introducing the link. Both question and its answer are very interesting.

Answer (score 9):

[As coincidentally came up recently](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2482/reword-what-topics-can-i-ask-about-here), questions on this site should typically be related to research in mathematics (not questions in mathematics related to research).

A [very good answer to a similar question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1654/are-professional-physicists-computer-scientists-engineers-economists-not-a/1662#1662) was given by Kaveh, let me quote some key bits:

> [Q]uestions have to be stated clearly and in a way which is understandable to mathematicians. Keep in mind that the audience of the site are mathematicians. 
>   It is mainly the job of the person asking the question 
>   to state the question clearly and rigorously in the language of mathematicians.

And:

> When
>
> - you have good reasons to believe that a mathematician can answer the question and 
>     that the expertise of a mathematician is required to answer it,
> - you have spend time to write a clear question in the language of mathematicians,
> - you have written a brief motivation section explaining why you are interested in the question,
> - you have demonstrated that you have done your own research and 
>     have tried to answer your question yourself first,
>
> then it is much more likely that your question will get positive feedback on MO[...]

For questions mainly pertaining to historical matters you could consider the site on [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: And of course if the question really is of a mathematical nature but not of interest to mathematicians, math.stackexchange.com might well be a good place for it (still assuming it can be formulated to be understandable by mathematicians).

Comment: To complement quid's good answer let me add that I would regard mathematical questions arising from good-level research in other areas as  both interesting to (at least to some) mathematicians, and as representing research-in-mathematics appropriate for MO.  Of course, the question should be genuinly a question-in-mathematics. Amit, I suggest you will state your actual question in the body of your meta question or as a comment.

Comment: @GilKalai In fact it is a (not too long) *series* of questions not a single one. I think it is not suitable to mention them here in Meta but they are generally similar to what Joseph O'Rourke linked in his comment.

Comment: @AmitSingMukerjee then why not give the first of the series?